# Print stylesheet - links & images

Tags: css, printing

I am creating a print stylesheet for an online community. Stylesheet is no problem except ... safari and firefox seem to be adding an element containing link url (dunno for ie yet).

I want a 'clean' print-out of a list without link-urls, any thoughts on how to get rid of them.
(don't suggest to include text in non-link elements ;-)

[image: unwanted print links]

Comment: what's the html look like? pictures aren't of much use for fixing html-level problems

Comment: `a{ display: none; }` comes to mind. Like Marc said, it would be better if you showed your HTML and CSS.

Comment: point is, <a href="..."> shows the href attribute contents when printing ... I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

safari and firefox are styling links by snagging the url via attribute selectors, check in web inspector for specifics, but i'm guessing it's something like this: `a[href=""]:after{content:""}`, which you can override by setting `a[href=""]:after{display:none}`

Comment: or setting content to normal ... accepting your answer though because of the web inspector tip!   Tx.

Answer (score 8):

Okay guys, sorry ... just an answer for future reference ...

This does the trick to reset the link-styles :-)

```
a, a:after { content: normal !important; }
```